# SQL Server - PIVOT Grouping

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this confusing thing on using pivot in grouping per EmployeeID.

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT  LoanAmount, lt.LoanTypeID
    FROM LoanContract lc
        INNER JOIN LoanType lt ON lt.LoanTypeID = lc.LoanTypeID
    GROUP BY EmployeeID, LoanAmount, lt.LoanTypeID
)src
PIVOT(
    SUM(LoanAmount)
    FOR LoanTypeID IN ([1], [2], [3], [4],  [5])
)piv;
```

There are 2 employeeID which is emp=1 has a sum(lt.LoanAmount) that is associated with lt.LoanTypeID = 5 and on the other hand emp2 has a sum(lt.LoanAmount) that is associated with lt.LoanTypeID 1 and 2

The result(1) shows:

```
[1]         [2]        [3]     [4]      [5]    
2400.00 30000.00    NULL    NULL    105000.00
```

Expected result(2):

```
[1]         [2]        [3]     [4]      [5]  
NULL         NULL       NULL    NULL     105000.00
2400.00      30000.00   NULL    NULL     NULL
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just need  `SELECT  EmployeeId, LoanAmount, lt.LoanTypeID`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try selecting employeeId as well in the subquery:

```
select *
from (
    select employeeID, -- here
        LoanAmount,
        lt.LoanTypeID
    from LoanContract lc
    inner join LoanType lt on lt.LoanTypeID = lc.LoanTypeID
    group by EmployeeID,
        LoanAmount,
        lt.LoanTypeID
    ) src
PIVOT(
    SUM(LoanAmount) 
    for LoanTypeID in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])
    ) piv;
```

Comment: Thanks pal, appreciated